# Ray picking in android - how to manage different shapes

Tags: android, opengl-es, ray-picking

I`m confused. I've read a lot of different tutorials related with ray picking. But every time those example are based on some simple shape, square or triangle. In each example for each shape there is a function that is checking this specific shape. How it should be managed without that ? I have different and unnatural shapes, how it can be managed ?

Comment: How accurate does the ray picking need to be? Why can't you use a set of simple shapes for a single odd shape to implement intersection?

Comment: @MorrisonChang for now it is not be very accurate so if you may say something more about your idea that would be great. I'm not sure how can I take an OpenGL object generated from the .obj file and divide to to simple shapes

Answer (score 0):

For 2D polygons, I use the Winding number point inside a polygon as described here:
http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html

Near the bottom is C code implementation that is pretty simple to port.

Your polygon hulls are a (closed) list of points.